# Intellij - refactor getters and setters using delegate class

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, refactoring

Here's what I'd like to do. Let's say I have this code:

```
public class Foo {

  private Bar bar = new Bar();

  public void doWork() {
    bar.setA(5);
    bar.setB(10);
  }
}

public class Bar {
  private int a;
  private int b;

  public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
  public void setB(int b) { this.b = b; }

  ...
}
```

I want to extract members a and b from Bar into a separate Container class and end up with this code. Notice that Foo doesn't call setA on bar anymore, instead it requests container and calls a setter on it instead:

```
public class Foo {

  private Bar bar = new Bar();

  public void doWork() {
    bar.getContainer.setA(5);
    bar.getContainer.setB(10);
  }
}


public class Bar {
  private Container container;

  public Container getContainer() { return container; }

  ...
}

public class Container {
  private int a;
  private int b;

  public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
  public void setB(int b) { this.b = b; }

  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ?

I could try using Refactor -> Extract -> Delegate, but in that case IntelliJ leaves setA and setB methods in Bar and doesn't change code in Foo:

```
public class Bar {
  private Container container;

  public void setA(int a) { container.setA(a); }
  public void setB(int b) { container.setB(b); }

  ...
}
```

which is not quite what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Select the piece of code inside class bar...

```
private int a;
private int b;

public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
public void setB(int b) { this.b = b; }
```

On the main menu, or from the context menu of the selection, choose Refactor | Extract | Method Object . You will also have option to choose to create inner class, or anonymous class. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. IDE shows an error tooltip "Cannot perform refactoring. Selected block should represent a set of statements or an expression"